# Converting String to a Short Array - Java

Tags: java, android, string, short

I am trying to convert a string of numbers (e.g "34 4 5 6 67 45 34") into an array of shorts.

I have written the following code :

```
//Split the string and then build a short array with the values.
            String[] tabOfShortString = finalString.split(" ");
            int length = tabOfShortString.length;
            System.out.println("Length of float string is" + length);
            short[] shortsArray = new short[length];
            for (int l = 0; l < length; l++) {
                //System.out.println("l is currently "+l);
                Short res = new Short(tabOfShortString[l]);
                System.out.println("Indice Short Value is " + res);
                shortsArray[l] = res;
            }
```

The problem is that the finished array (shortsArray) is not accurately capturing my string. Can anyone spot what may be wrong ?

Thank you.

Comment: what seems to be the problem?

Comment: What do you mean by `not accurately`? Can you give an example?

Comment: Can you explain what "not accurately capturing my string" means?

Comment: Please show a short but complete program which demonstrates the problem, including the expected output and the actual output.

Comment: Output is right as per your string,,,,

Comment: I have a string of 630 values. When I use the code above the float array is correct up to about half-way through, at which point it seems to skip about 10 or so values.

Comment: What are the values from where the incorrect output start? E.g. if the incorrect value starts from index 315, please provide values from index 310 through 350). Please keep in mind the minimum and maximum values a short can hold in Java (-32768 and 32767 respectively).

Edit: You can provide the string representation of that segment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your solution works for me, this is what I have:

```
public static short[] toShorts(String finalString) {
    String[] tabOfShortString = finalString.split(" ");
    int length = tabOfShortString.length;
    System.out.println("Length of float string is" + length);
    short[] shortsArray = new short[length];
    for (int l = 0; l < length; l++) {
        //System.out.println("l is currently "+l);
        Short res = new Short(tabOfShortString[l]);
        System.out.println("Indice Short Value is " + res);
        shortsArray[l] = res;
    }

    return shortsArray;

}
```

Then I call this:

```
short[] qux = toShorts("34 4 5 6 67 45 34");
```

And the output of qux is:

```
[34, 4, 5, 6, 67, 45, 34]
```

I do not see a problem?

Answer (score 0):

Break That using StringTokenizer first you have to calculate number for white spaces in the String and then apply loop to extract value from string

```
int count=0;
String text= "34 4 5 6 67 45 34";

for(int i=0; i<text.length(); i++)
{
while(text.charAt(i)==' ')
{
count++;
}
}

StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(String);

for(int j=0;j<count;j++){
Short res[] = new Short(st.nextToken());

}
```

Comment: How would this solve the problem? In-fact the counting loop is not required when using StringTokenizer.

`
StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(finalString, " ");
Short array[] = new Short[st.countTokens()];
int index = 0;
while(st.hasMoreElements())
    array[index++] = Short.parseShort((String)st.nextElement());
`

Comment: And actually the while loop would run infinitely in case of even a single space.

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps beacuse you array is of the primitive type`short`and you try to add a `java.lang.Short`object.

**edit** I was wrong...

Comment: No, autounboxing takes care of that.